# PostgreSQL - Convert year to date

Tags: postgresql

The **year** is given as **int**: 2009, 2010 etc.
I want to **convert** this information to **DATE** (first January).

My solutions (I prefer the first one):

```
(year::char || '-01-01')::DATE
'0001-01-01' + ((year-1)::char || ' year')::interval
```

Is there a better (build in) or more elegant and faster solution?
(I'm currently working with **PostgreSQL 8.4** but are also interested in more recent versions.)

Comment: Your problem description is a bit loose:  PostgreSQL (8.4) has no single-argument `to_char()` nor a TINYINT type.

Comment: String literals are single quoted `'-01-01'` in SQL. Double quotes are reserved for identifiers.

Comment: watch those quote characters! Single quotes for values, double quotes (only) for identifiers (parts of the schema: column names etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! 
Of course you are all right - I wasn't too careful typing the example. The mix-up of PostgreSQL versions is based on reading of different sources and different installations (local and remote).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
to_date(year::varchar, 'yyyy')
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL, `text` is preferable to `varchar`. And `'yyyy'` should be `'YYYY'` if I read the PostgreSQL manual correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT to_date(2011::text, 'YYYY');
```

Attention: any code based on default casting from text to date is bad. Somebody can change a default format *datestyle* to some unexpected value, and this code fails. Using to_date or to_timestamp is very preferable. *to_date* or *to_timestamp* is relative expensive, but it is rock robust.

Comment: +1 for *DateStyle* caveat.  However, in this particular example, is there any *DateStyle* input mode that does not correctly understand YYYY-MM-DD?  (The [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) suggest there is not.)

Comment: I hope so YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD will be parsed everywhere - but it is not ensured.

Answer (score 2):

```
to_date('01 Jan ' || year, 'DD Mon YYYY')
```

OR

```
SELECT (DATE (year || '-01-01'))
```

ref: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html
Note: I haven't worked with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
select year * '1 year'::interval + '0000-01-01'::date;
```

I like this way because it avoids conversion between text and integer (once all the constants are parsed).

Comment: Interesting approach.  However it gives `ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-01-01"` under pg 9.1.

Comment: Also, as a trivial observation, this recipe will return a TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE rather than a DATE, though I suspect that matters not at all in the common case.

Comment: ah, I was testing it on a pg8.3 instance. Maybe this depends on if you build with floating-point vs int times?